# Django Contect_processor reversed list

Tags: python, django, reverse

I'm working with django and trying to make a context_processor who´s going to make a list of newsposts which can be shown in my base template. My code look like this.

```
from news.models import Post

def get_news_title(request):
    return{
        'get_news_title': Post.objects.all().reverse()[:5]
    }
```

But still it just show my first 5 newsposts...

Any tips?

Comment: So do you want your _last_ 5 posts instead of the first? You're not ordering your queryset explicitly — does your `Post` model define any default ordering at all?

Comment: Do you have an `ordering` attribute in the `class Meta` of the model ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Django docs say explicitly that

> reverse() should generally only be called on a QuerySet which has a
>   defined ordering (e.g., when querying against a model which defines a
>   default ordering, or when using order_by()). If no such ordering is
>   defined for a given QuerySet, calling reverse() on it has no real
>   effect (the ordering was undefined prior to calling reverse(), and
>   will remain undefined afterward).

so you need to use `order_by('some field here')`.

For example:

```
Post.objects.order_by('id').reverse()[:5]
```

See docs for [order_by()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.order_by)

Comment: While it might work in most cases, Ordering by `id` is not necessarliy a foolproof way of getting the latest objects. If there is a datetime field for add in the model, we should use that.

Comment: Yes you're right, but I don't know what is the model there, so I just gave it as an example.

Comment: I agree. It was just an observation. I dont think your answer is _wrong_ per say

Comment: by date will be better.